# Access Textview delegate in a custom tableviewcell from a tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

So I have a custom tablecell which has a Textview ,Now I have tableview which use this tableviewcell

Now the tableview has a Button "Save" , Now I want it to enable or disable  based on the input in the textview ,

In table view cell I have declare the Textview delegate for changes in text

ListViewCell.m

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
NSLog(@"textViewDidBeginEditing:");
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

in

ListViewItem.m

implementation done in  cellForRowAtIndexPath ,

So when I run the application and input some value in textview it show the nslog message

```
2014-08-16 19:35:27.817 Click2List[1365:60b] textViewDidBeginEditing:
```

Now the question is to how to know if the text has been entered from  the main view  ????

I think it's a simple solution which I am unable to think :(((

Note : I have tried to put the the textview delegate in ListViewItem.m but no success

Comment: You can make your own delegate in the listviewcell and relay the information to the main view through your own delegate. Or you can pass your main view instance to the listviewcell so that the listviewcell has access directly to the main view, then relay the information.

Comment: Yep got it , it worked , some time you think too hard for a solution , thanks for the solution